# How to run a hosted ironpython 1.1 from an Excel add-in?

Tags: excel, com, ironpython

I am writing an Excel add-in that hosts IronPython 1.1 and I want to
provide the Excel.Application COM object to the PythonEngine instance.

My C# can access members of the COM object just fine. However, when my
IronPython script accesses members of the COM object, I get a
"System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be
converted to type 'System.UInt32&'."

Here is my C# code hosting IronPython 1.1:

```
public void ExecuteFile(string path) {
    // see if COM object works
    Debug.WriteLine(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Caption); 

    engine.Globals.Add("excel", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application);

    try
    {
        engine.ExecuteFile(path);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

and here is my IronPython test script:

`excel.ActiveSheet.Range['A1'].Value2 = 42` // throws exception mentioned above

Comment: Have you tried doing what your python script is doing through C#? Does that work? I know, you said access works fine, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: I've tried that. For instance this line of C# prints the value of cell A4:

  Debug.WriteLine("C#: " + \
    this.Range["A4", missing].Value2.ToString()
  );
            
While this line of python throws the mentioned exception:

  Debug.WriteLine("Python: " + \ 
    sheet.Range["A4", Missing].Value2.ToString()
  )

Where 'sheet' is a variable provided to the hosted ironpython engine.

Comment: A couple of Excel COM methods and properties work ok (Application.Visible is ok IIRC) but most fail with the exception mentioned. I tried doing a similar project targeting Word and it seems to work just fine. I am running VS2008, Office2007, Vista SP1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to set .Value you need to "index" it with the datatype; it's more convenient to set .Value2 instead (it can be set directly).  So what happens if you use .Value2 instead of .Value in that Python assignment?

Answer (score 0):

A good article with explanations and a solution is here:

http://codeidol.com/csharp/c-sharp-in-office/Working-with-Excel-Objects/Special-Excel-Issues/

Basically, I opted for disabling the VSTO proxy which wraps the Excel COM object. It can be done with this line in AssemblyInfo.cs:

[assembly: ExcelLocale1033(false)]